# Add controller to Prestashop module

Tags: php, controller, prestashop

I am using the payment module that puts prestashop in GitHub as an example, but when adding a new controller I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'paymentexampleMyControllerModuleFrontController' not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/htdocs/classes/controller/Controller.php:208
```

Check the builder which is shown as follows:

```
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    $this->author = 'PrestaShop';
    $this->controllers = array('validation', 'MyController');
```

I already cleared cache and gave reset to the module but I keep getting the same error, I use prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you declare it?

It should be:

```
class PaymentExampleMyControllerModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
```

and the location should be:

If a legacy controller controllers/front.

If a Symfony controller src/controller/front